# Append to Existing excel without changing formatting

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to take data from other excel/csv sheets and append them to an existing workbook/worksheet. The code below works in terms of appending, however, it removes formatting for not only the sheet I've appended, but all other sheets in the workbook.

From what I understand, the reason this happens is because I'm reading the entire ExcelWorkbook as a dictionary, turning it into a Pandas Dataframe, and then rewriting it back into Excel. But I'm not sure how to go about it otherwise.

How do I need to modify my code to make it so that I'm only appending the data I need, and leaving everything else untouched? Is pandas the incorrect way to go about this?

```
import os  
import pandas as pd  
import openpyxl  


#Read Consolidated Sheet as Dictionary
#the 'Consolidation' excel sheet has 3 sheets: 
#Consolidate, Skip1, Skip2

ws_dict = pd.read_excel('.\Consolidation.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

#convert relevant sheet to datafarme
mod_df = ws_dict['Consolidate']

#check that mod_df is the 'Consolidate' Tab
mod_df

#do work on mod_df
#grab extra sheets with data and make into pd dataframes
excel1 = 'doc1.xlsx'
excel2 = 'doc2.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(excel1)
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)

df2 = pd.read_excel(excel2)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)

#concate the sheets
mod_df = pd.concat([mod_df, df1, df2], axis=0, ignore_index = True, sort=False)

#reassign the modified to the sheet
ws_dict['Consolidate'] = mod_df

#write to the consolidation workbook
with pd.ExcelWriter('Consolidation.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    for ws_name, df_sheet in ws_dict.items():
        df_sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=ws_name, index=False)
```

Comment: you're importing openpyxl but not using it. I'm not familiar with pandas, but I suspect it does not preserve formatting information. Have you tried opening the workbook with [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) and then writing the pandas data via openpyxl instead?